# Installing Docker with no network

Tags: docker

I am trying to install docker on a linux box with no network. I have searched my question on this forum and other resources and gathered all the rpms fols suggested that we will need for a no network installation. I musy have installed all the dependencies, i.e.e container-selinux, etc. and I am down to the last error which I can't figure out how to fix:

```
sudo rpm -ivh docker-ce-18.06.1.ce-3.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

It reports that `libltdl.so.7()(64bit)` is missing. I could do a yunm install for docker-compose but without having docker, it's useless. And if I skip the dependencies, it installs but won't start, even if I create the docker.socket manually.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

On a test machine that is connected to the internet install yum downloader:

```
# yum install yum-utils
```

Download the RPMs:

```
# yumdownloader --destdir=/var/tmp/ --resolve docker-ce
```

Copy all of the RPMs from /var/tmp to the target machine (with no internet connection) and install the deps RPMs first and after install the docker RPM